# Showing that $\vartheta: \mathbb { Z } _ { m } \rightarrow \mathbb { Z } _ { n }$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $\vartheta: \mathbb { Z } _ { m } \rightarrow \mathbb { Z } _ { n }$ taking $x$
to $a x$, where $a$ an
idempotent of $\mathbb { Z } _ { n }$ with  $| a |$ divides $m$ is a ring homomorphism.

I know that if I manage to show that $n$ divides $m$ then it will follow from " [Suppose that $n$ divides $m$ and that $a$ is an idempotent of $Z_n$. Show that the mapping $x \rightarrow ax$ is a ring homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871241/suppose-that-n-divides-m-and-that-a-is-an-idempotent-of-z-n-show-that-t) ". However, how can I show that $n$ divides $m$?

Answer (score 1):

You know that the image of $1$ has to be $a$ but then you have that
$$0=\theta(0)=\theta(\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_m) = ma$$ 
so you have that if you multiply $a$ for $m$ you obtains $0$.
Such an element exists in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ only if $n$ divides $m$.